# Suppose $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D$. Prove that $A × B = (A × D) \cap (C × B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that if
$A \subset C$ then $a \in A$ and $a \in C$
and if
$B \subset D$ then $b \in B$ and $b \in D$

Also if $A × B = \{(a,b)| a \in A, b \in B\}$

But what is next steps?

Comment: Perform "element chasing."  Suppose $(a,b)\in A\times B$.  This means that... $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  In particular, since $a\in A$ and $A\subseteq C$ this implies that $a\in C$ and we remind ourselves that $b\in B$ still, and so these together imply that $(a,b)\in C\cap B$.  Continue in this fashion and conclude that the LHS is indeed a subset of the RHS of what you want to prove.  Do the same and show that the RHS is a subset of the LHS to complete the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A \times D)\cap(C \times B)=(A \cap C)\times (D\cap B)=A \times B$